# touchpad problems in newly installed ubuntu 20.10

Tags: 20.10

I got new Ubuntu 20.10 installed on my laptop.I am using 20.10 for 1st time. I am experiencing some touch-pad related issues as mentioned below. Please help me solve them. Thanks in advance for your help.

1,When I tap the touch-pad with single finger or double fingers(double fingers for right click), a red circle starts to form around the cursor. This is an unwanted feature. How to remove that?

2.Suppose I search something on Google. There are multiple lists showing for the search result. Then I want to open 1 link in new tab. For that, I press 2 fingers on touch-pad. Then a circle starts forming around the cursor. When the circle is completely formed, a window appears. There is an option- open in new tab. I click that option and new tab is opened. But the original tab does not remain unchanged. It changes to open the same new web link and does not show the search results. This is an unwanted feature. how to remove that?

3.I opened the terminal. I want to copy some text from the terminal. I selected the text. Then I want to do right click and copy. So, I tap 2 fingers on touch-pad. A new window opens where copy, paste options are shown. But the text which I selected earlier becomes un selected and the copy option is disabled. How to solve this?

I tried to search for this on Google but did not find any good solutions.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the red circle forming around the cursor when tapped, do the following:

Settings -> Universal Access -> Click Assist (disable it to remove the red circle)